# What are these triangles along the model edges?

Tags: modeling

[image]

They tend to fluctuate as I move the model around:

[image]

Comment: Looks like precision artifacts from clipping distance issues. Adjust you viewport clipping distances, reduce the gap between them

Comment: Ah yep that was it. The far plane was too far away: https://imgur.com/a/tMN7S

Answer (score 2):

These are precision artifacts from clipping distance issues caused by the distance between the clipping planes being too great:

[image]

I reduced the far plane to 1m.